# AS3 Array Limits?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I've ran into a weird problem with flash, I have an array of 92 buttons, at first it was all contained in a single array, the buttons up to the first 20th buttons work, the rest don't.

The buttons will take the user to the next scene basically.

So I tried to breakup the array into multiple arrays, so the first array contains the first 20, the second array the 21-40th and so on, the fifth array contains the 81-92 buttons. 
The problem now is I will get this error message:

```
TypeError #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties
```

and it'll break all the buttons, rendering all the buttons unusable.

Therefore, I commented out the

```
for (var a=0; a<buttons.length; a++)
{
    firstarray[a].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ArraySelectOne); 
    secondarray[a].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ArraySelectOne); 
    thirdarray[a].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ArraySelectOne); 
    fourtharray[a].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ArraySelectOne); 
    //fiftharray[a].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ArraySelectOne); 
}
```

in my button spawn function and the buttons from the first to fourth array works flawlessly well except the fifth, which when clicked, nothing happens.

So I tired to create a new function whereby it was only the fiftharray in it and called the new function in the spawner, same error, breaks everything.

Then I thought was there a button naming issue whereby i mistyped something, I took the button names in the fifth array and pasted them into the start of the fourtharray, replacing what was in it plus commenting out the fiftharray from my script.

The once unworkable buttons (81 to 92) worked, but now (61 to 80) didn't.

I tried combining all the arrays using the comarray, but only the first 20 buttons worked.

So I am wondering if is there a fix or something to solve this problem, much help is appreciated!

Comment: I don't know what `buttons` represents, but I'm guessing `buttons.length` is greater than 12, so on the 13th loop iteration, you are trying to add an event listener to button 93...

Comment: There's also not an array limit as low as you're looking, so there's more likely an issue somewhere else in your code.

Comment: The arrays are my containers for my buttons placed in the movieclip, so the buttons I'm calling are the individual instances in the movieclip.

For what the buttons mean, I followed this tutorial http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lTvuRIsG9yY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to have multiple arrays, remove them. The last array is obviously shorter than the rest and that's messing up your code -> you are pointing to an index that doesn't exist in your last array.

There is actually no need to have an array. You have 92 buttons, that's a nice bunch. Why not to put it to a movieclip instead? What's the need of the array?

Let's assume you select all your buttons and put them inside of movieclip called *buttonsClip*. Now you can just use this code, without typing all the instance names out to put them to the array (like the tutorial did it... that may work for 8 buttons, but 92... come on :) ):

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

for(var i:uint=0; i<buttonsClip.numChildren; i++) {
    var b:MovieClip = buttonsClip.getChildAt(i) as MovieClip; //Assuming the buttons are movieclips
    b.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick);
}

function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void {
    trace(e.target.name);
}
```

Comment: Hahaha this may sound silly, but I followed what you said about the uneven array count, so for the last array, I duplicated the last button's instance name another 8 times, so it works flawlessly.

The purpose for the buttons was to move a movieclip to a specific
position, varied for each button.

Comment: You could just check whether the index of the last array is not null: *if(fiftharray[a]) fiftharray[a].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,ArraySelectOne);* It is more elegant. :)

Answer (score 0):

I know this Question is currently 8 years old, but maybe this will help another person that is searching for the same thing.

I had pretty much the same problem and in my case it was just that I accidently skipped a number while naming all the Symbols in the libary that I wanted to be in this array. I had 42 Symbols but because of this mistake the function to load the array had 43 and obviously the program was confused about that.